# Why does KeyEventArgs.KeyCode show a set of incorrect keys when debugging?

Tags: c#, keycode, keyeventargs

When processing a `KeyDown` event for the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, the `KeyCode` shows up as

> RButton | MButton | Back | Space

[image]

I can determine from the `Keys` enum that

```
RButton = 2
MButton = 4
Back = 8
Space = 32

Delete = 46
```

and

2 + 4 + 8 + 32 = 46

But why is this?

Comment: Because it's a `[Flags]` enum.

Comment: @SLaks That makes sense. This seems like a very strange way to show the `KeyCode` in the debugger though, as most people probably don't realize that, or have the `Keys` enum memorized